# Flutter and google_maps_flutter - add listener for "my location" button click (setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener?)

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have created a Flutter app that uses Google maps. It gets the user's location and centers on that point. As the user walks around the camera will follow it but ONLY if the user hasn't manually moved the camera themselves (_userMovedMap = 0). Once they have moved the map it will no longer follow them...

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
    ),
    body: Listener(
      onPointerMove: (e) {
        _userMovedMap = true;
      },
      child: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _center,
          zoom: _zoom,
        ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the location update listener, which also tells the camera to move if "_userMovedMap" is false :

```
Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position _newLocation) {

  //update position with new location data
  setState(() {
    _center = LatLng(_newLocation.latitude, _newLocation.longitude);
    //Move camera to center of location if !_userMovedMap
    if (!_userMovedMap) moveCamera();
  });
});
```

...this all works great.

But I want to listen for the user clicking the generic "my location" button (standard google button shown in the top-right of the map). The button can do what its supposed to (animates the camera to current location), but I aso want it to reset "_userMovedMap" to false again.
From what I've seen it's something to do with "setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener", but Google Maps Flutter widget doesn't recognise it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer - I don't think it is currently possible. It seems to be a "severe" request in a later googlemaps plugin update, but nothing is on the roadmap.
Therefore I made my own location button.